# how to put absolute url field in serializer model in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model like so:

```
class GiveAbsolute(serializers.Field):
    def to_native(self,value): 
         # this where it give an error (self doesn't have request)
         # what i want it to give full url 
         # like: http://www.blabla.com/othermodel/1
         return reverse('link_to_othermodel',
                         args=[value],
                         request=self.request)

class SomethingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # field with foreign key
    othermodel = GiveAbsolute(source="othermodel.id")
    class Meta:
        model=Something
        fields("fields1","othermodel")
```

is there a way to achieve this ? 
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing in DRF, that has an access to request object is the view, so you need to figure out how to pass your request from view to serializer, for example in generic ListView you can use `get_serializer`.

Then, when you already have it in your serializer, you can use `self.parent` (which is a parent serializer) to capture it from the field itself:

```
class GiveAbsolute(serializers.Field):
    def to_native(self,value):
        return reverse('link_to_othermodel',
                     args=[value],
                     request=self.parent.request)


class SomethingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # field with foreign key
    othermodel = GiveAbsolute(source="othermodel.id")
    class Meta:
        model=Something
        fields=("fields1","othermodel")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(SomethingSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class SomethingView(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Something
    serializer_class = SomethingSerializer

    def get_serializer(self, instance=None, data=None,
                   files=None, many=False, partial=False):

        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        context = self.get_serializer_context()
        return serializer_class(instance, data=data, files=files, many=many,
                                partial=partial, context=context, request=self.request)
```

Comment: somehow i got error `'module' object is not callable`. when i use `pdb.set_trace()` , `GiveAbsolute` get called first before `get_serializer` thus `self.parent.request` give `None` , any solution for this ? thanx

Comment: @whale_steward Can you please provide full stacktrace? also try using `reverse_lazy` instead of `reverse`..

Comment: thank you for pointing out to use `reverse_lazy` now is working perfectly

Answer (score 8):

From the [source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/5b2abbed25ef41c4cc1b3806037c6bd7631db327/rest_framework/generics.py#L135)

The request object is an entry of the context dictionary. ie.

request = self.context.get('request')

In your case, just do:

```
self.request = self.context.get('request')
```

then build the url

```
self.request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('some_url_name'))
```

Comment: Thanks, this post helped me in taking host name in serializer create method as it only provides self and validated_data in params.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer of mariodev, here is a reusable solution for Models ; I use it to provide URLs to service (see them as metheds) on django models.

## Reusable components

### serializers.py

```
class RequestAwareSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A serializer which fields can access the request object.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(RequestAwareSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class APIMethodField(serializers.Field):
    """ To get the absolute URL of a method accessible via the API
    """
    def __init__(self, url_action_name, *args, **kwargs):
        self._url_name = url_action_name
        super(APIMethodField, self).__init__(source='*', *args, **kwargs)

    def to_native(self, obj):
        """
        @param objid the ID of the object
        @param method_url_name, the name of the url, as in urls.py
        """
        return reverse_lazy(self._url_name, args=[obj.id],


                   request=self.parent.request)
```

### views.py

```
class ChattyModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """ ModelViewSet which informs the serializer about the request

    (abstract)
    """
    def get_serializer(self, instance=None, data=None,
                   files=None, many=False, partial=False):

        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        context = self.get_serializer_context()
        return serializer_class(instance, data=data, files=files, many=many,
                                partial=partial, context=context,
                                request=self.request)
```

## Example use

### urls.py

```
url(r'^v1/maildomain/(?P<maildomain_id>\d+)/check/$',
    views.MailDomainDetail.as_view(), name='maildomain_dns_check')
```

### serializers.py

```
class MailDomainSerializer(RequestAwareSerializer):
    checkdns_url = APIMethodField(url_action_name='maildomain_dns_check')

    class Meta:
        model = MailDomain()
        fields = ('name', 'checkdns_url')
```

### views.py

```
class MailDomainView(ChattyModelViewSet):
    model = MailDomain
    serializer_class = MailDomainSerializer
```

Comment: In Python 3, I used `to_representation` instead of `to_native`. without request