# How to make Django REST Framework return a list of hyperlinks instead of all data in one list?

Tags: python, django, api, rest

I'm creating a REST API in Python/Django using the popular Django REST Framework.

I stumbled upon something however.

I have an API call in the code fragment below to display all memes.

This returns a list of all the known information about all the memes in the database... How can I make the Django REST Framework return a LIST of hyperlinks and all the information about a specific meme behind every hyperlink? Or isn't this considered "RESTful"? I'm sorry, but there's so much FUD on the internet about REST these days, I'm still learning this stuff. :-)

Thanks in advance for any tips!

K.

```
(django)kristof@kristof:~/dev/projects/sandbox$ curl -i -H "Authorization: Token 3fcb196896cf361a586f200cd05d1fb76dc595e9" -X GET http://api.sandbox.dev:8080/memes/
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Sat, 04 Oct 2014 19:23:18 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/json
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS

[{"id": 2, "name": "Overly Attached Girlfriend"}, {"id": 1, "name": "Good Guy Greg"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

To make myself somewhat clearer: I want the endpoint at /memes/ return a LIST of URLs of the memes in the database with more details about every meme behind every URL.

What I want the endpoint to return is hence something like this:

```
["http://api.sandbox.dev:8080/memes/2/", "http://api.sandbox.dev:8080/memes/1/"]
```

Instead of the list with already ALL the details of every meme.

Answer (score 1):

In your serializer class, add a to_representation method in version 3 (it is to_native in version 2 I think).

```
def to_representation(self, obj):
    # maniputale your object here to create the hyperlink
    hyperlink = "/link/details/%s" % obj.id
    return hyperlink
```

The return value of this method is one element in your response list.

[Custom output with serializer in Django Rest Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957924/custom-output-with-serializer-in-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 0):

Well

it seems that you are receiving a Json. Convert it from json and you will have your list

```
a = '[{"id": 2, "name": "Overly Attached Girlfriend"}, {"id": 1, "name": "Good Guy Greg"}]'
import json
type(json.loads(a))
list
```

There are somethings you should be aware of when using loads, like code injection. Google it to have a notion

Comment: Thanks for the tip, that could come in handy for other things. Your answer also made me realize that I maybe haven't made myself clear. :-) See my other comment: I want the endpoint to return a list of URLs (with more details behind every URL) instead of converting the current JSON list to a Python object. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: try checking the post. I think it will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21898043/how-to-put-absolute-url-field-in-serializer-model-in-django-rest-framework